# getting this npm ERR! 503 Service Unavailable - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/cra-template/-/cra-template-1.1.2.tgz while npx create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, registry, create-react-app

**error in npx create-react-app**

> Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
> Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

> npm ERR! code E503
> npm ERR! 503 Service Unavailable - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/cra-template/-/cra-template-1.1.2.tgz

> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /home/vkammari/.npm/_logs/2021-09-25T13_28_53_367Z-debug.log

**using node version - 14.17.6
npm,npx version - 6.14.15**

[log of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H61pc.png)